# Determine a fixed, defined period / value, Pine Script

Tags: return-value, pine-script, defined, back-testing

How can I set a defined value.
In backtesting, the bars are processed from back to front. Is it possible in Pine Script that, for example, a certain function is always carried out on the last 3rd bar.

for example:

IF 3rd bar from the front THEN x: = x + 1

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue. But you can hold last 3 bars info using the "[1]" notation. close[1] would be last close, high[2] would be ante-last high, low[3] would be 3rd low from now etc... I don't know if that helps. Otherwise please reformulate your question with a more precise example ;)

Comment: Delete your answer. You need to write back in commentaries below here. I guess maybe you didn't have sufficient reputation to write commentaries yet. Just delete it anyways, I'll write an answer for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want at any bar you want: you just need to specify your function within an `if` block where the condition must be true for the given bar you target.

```
if ( this_bar_is_the_bar_i_want_to_target )
    // ... do stuff like x+1 etc...
```

Now you might ask "How to get ante-last bar ?". Basically, you can't because "ante-last bar" is relative and infinite. Meaning, on a 1 hour timeframe, at 11:00, the ante-last bar will be 10:00, but then at 12:00, the ante-last bar is not 10:00 anymore, it now is 11:00... and this is infinite.

Now, that being said, "ante-last bar" is dynamic, so it will always be changing after each new candle. So the correct approach would be to actually isolate the "current last bar" and from THIS last bar, try to work your calculations on the previous one. In that case, it would be something like that:

```
if (barstate.islast)
    // ... do stuff with close[1] or high[1] or low[1] or open[1] ...
```

That means that you can isolate the last bar DYNAMICALLY (it will be another bar for each new candle in the chart), and from there you can call previous bar, or bar from 3 bars back, ...

Comment: Hi Jona, thank you very much for your quick and helpful answer.

The problem is that the most function inside a for-next-loop not work. So "barstate.islast" do not work inside correct.

Please look here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/68699360/16327266

There you can see and better understand where the problem is. I am sure you have a solution.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have very hard time understanding what you try to achieve actually. Most of the issues posted here, like yours, isolate ONE micro-problem, but the GLOBAL APPROACH is the actual issue... If you want help, it might be much more efficient to post the general idea of what you try to achieve to give you the best approach. In fact, as your other "for next" issue, sometimes pine-script is not able to do things. This is why one should think the solution from the beginning, and not in a narrow micro-issue. Hope you understand what I mean :)